# Fatal error: Class 'Altima_Lookbook_Helper_Data' not found in /home/offerbea/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547

Tags: magento-1.8, error, backend, class

I have installed it from magento connect,  and now in my back-end it displayed as it.
Please somebody help me how to fix it.
I gues it causing by i was put the compliation mode in on.
Thank you

Comment: put the compilation mode 'off'. Then refresh the cache and logout and login back. Still the error is there, check whether the installed module contains a helper class as Data.php. If exists check the class name is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Please Check in your Module like

If your module in Local folder then

app/code/local/Altima/Lookbook/Helper/Data.php file Available or not if not then please create the file as below code.

```
<?php
  class Altima_Lookbook_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
  {
  }
```

Now refresh your cache and test it